# how to go other page on dropdown selection using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist box on my page.. with A B C D E F
each pages have different images.

Once If I select A I need display one Image like B I need to display other image/table on the page.

Can any one tel me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use jQuery, quick example to get you started:

```
$('#dropDownList').change(
    function() { 
        $('#contentDiv').html("<img src='yourjpg.jpg' alt='alt text' />"); 
    });
```

You will want to check some values and pick the correct jpg based on the value selected, but that should get you started.